# Why isn't this form element updating?

Tags: javascript

I've got a form with an undetermined number of text inputs that I'm trying to build some auto complete functionality into. The user starts typing in 'upl_band1' and bandlookup() builds the suggestion list. When the user clicks on the li with the mouse, bandfill() is executed, and 'upl_band1' should be updated.

Here's the form source...

```
<div>
    <input id="upl_band1" type="text" onblur="bandhide('upl_band1');" onkeyup="bandlookup(this.value,'upl_band1');" size="25" name="upl_band1" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div id="upl_band1sug" class="suggestionsBox" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="upArrow" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" src="upArrow.png">
    <div id="upl_band1auto" class="suggestionList">
        <li onclick="bandfill('Cedric Gervais','upl_band1');">Cedric Gervais</li>
        <li onclick="bandfill('Cee-Lo Green','upl_band1');">Cee-Lo Green</li>
        <li onclick="bandfill('Celine Dion','upl_band1');">Celine Dion</li>
        <li onclick="bandfill('Celleste','upl_band1');">Celleste</li>
        <li onclick="bandfill('Cerrone','upl_band1');">Cerrone</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the bandfill() function.

```
function bandfill(thisValue, boxName) {
    var s = boxName+"sug";
    $("#"+boxName).val(thisValue); // This is the line that isn't working.
    $("#"+s).hide();
}
```

I'm stuck on why that line isn't filling 'upl_band1' like I think it should. Help!

**Edit: I was asked to include bandhide() and bandlookup(). These work as they should.**

```
function bandlookup(bandString, boxName) {
    if(bandString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        var s = boxName+"sug";
        $("#"+s).hide();
    } else {
        var su = boxName+"sug";
        var suauto = boxName+"auto";
        $.post("band.php", {queryString: ""+bandString+"", inputName: ""+boxName+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length > 0) {
                $("#"+su).show();
                $("#"+suauto).html(data);
            }
            else if(data.length == 0) {
                $("#"+su).hide();
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function bandhide(boxName) {
    var s = boxName+"sug";
    $("#"+s).hide();
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for the `bandlookup` and `bandhide` functions, as well?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/TnRxC/1/ - so maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Your markup is constructed somewhat oddly. You have list items inside of a div rather than a list element such as ul or ol.

Comment: just of note: since you are using jQuery you should consider binding your events in the $(document).ready using jQuery.bind() , jQuery.delegate(), jQuery.click(), etc...

Comment: @John: or just use jQuery UI autocomplete instead: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: @mblase75....very true, but I wanted to make the suggestion to bind to events using jQuery because if all his events are handled as this example, meaning other forms and such, he should consider cleaning it up.

Comment: @kinakuta: "Oddly" is a nice way of putting it. Technically, the markup is invalid, not just odd ;)

Comment: @Flambino :) just trying to be gentle to new posters.

Comment: @kinakuta: Oh, I know, and I didn't mean to be harsh to the poster in my comment. I just thought it would be good to make it clear. Odd markup is fine, but invalid markup is less so :)

Comment: @John - I'm not going to pretend to know what that means. I'm just trying to get a basic autocomplete into this form, and this is the only autocomplete that I've had working.

Comment: @nrabinowitz This code was actually working before a server switch. Your link confirms to me that it should be working.

Comment: @kinakuta I realize this - that piece of code wasn't actually mine, and putting in the ul tag messes up the layout for some reason, thus I've left it.